# Spring Boot MongoDB Aggregation with ReplaceRoot / How to get the Most Recent Item in a Group

Tags: spring, mongodb, aggregation

I want to get the result of this MongoDB query in a Spring Boot Application.

```
db.getCollection('contentSource').aggregate( [ { $sort: { "modified": -1 } }, 
{ $group: { _id: "$sourceId", cs: { $push: "$$ROOT" } }}, 
{ $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $arrayElemAt: ['$cs', 0] } }} ] )
```

Does anyone know  how to add the replaceRoot to my Aggregation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    SortOperation sortOperation = new SortOperation(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC,"modified"));

        GroupOperation groupOperation = group("sourceId").push("$$ROOT").as("cs");

        Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation( sortOperation , groupOperation);

AggregationOperation replaceRoot = Aggregation.replaceRoot().withValueOf(ArrayOperators.ArrayElemAt.arrayOf("cs").elementAt(0));

        AggregationResults<Document> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation,"contentSource", replaceRoot,  Document.class);


        return result.getMappedResults();
```